# У меня есть три меню, когда я помещаю курсор в первую точку, первые пункты активируются в других меню, и так во всех пунктах меню

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$('a')
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    var elem = $(this).attr('id');
    $('[id=' + elem + ']').addClass('Active').siblings().removeClass('Active');
  })
  .on('mouseleave', function() {
    var elem = $(this).attr('id');
    $('[id=' + elem + ']').removeClass('Active');
  });
```

```css
.Active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#_" id="profileRed">Menu Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" id="profileBlue">Menu Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" id="profilePink">Menu Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" id="profileGreen">Menu Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#_" id="profileRed">Menu Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" id="profileBlue">Menu Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" id="profilePink">Menu Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" id="profileGreen">Menu Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#_" id="profileRed">Menu Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" id="profileBlue">Menu Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" id="profilePink">Menu Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" id="profileGreen">Menu Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Добавьте ровно столько кода, чтобы пример стал рабочим.

Comment: Мне нужна помощь, чтобы придумать правильный ответ.

Comment: Id на странице нельзя чтоб повторялся!! делайте классами

Comment: но если мы используем "data-id"?

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul.menu>li>a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#_" id="profileRed">Menu Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" id="profileBlue">Menu Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" id="profilePink">Menu Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" id="profileGreen">Menu Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#_" id="profileRed">Menu Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" id="profileBlue">Menu Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" id="profilePink">Menu Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" id="profileGreen">Menu Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#_" id="profileRed">Menu Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" id="profileBlue">Menu Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" id="profilePink">Menu Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" id="profileGreen">Menu Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Это хорошо, но использовать разные дизайны меню и JQuery.Спасибо

Comment: @AlexandruSmolenschi Я не понимаю, что Вы говорите.

Answer (score 0):

*Ответ переписан после уточняющих комментариев.*

Вы можете использовать на data-атрибуты, чтобы не пересекаться со стилями меню. Имя для data-атрибута вы выбираете сами. В моем примере это `data-item-role`.

В качестве альтернативного решения можно добавить каждому элементу меню специальный класс с префиксом `.js-`. Такие классы не используются при стилизации, а сам префикс служит для разработчиков указателем на то, что данный класс нужен для какого-то заскриптованного функционала и на него не нужно вешать какие-либо стили.

К примеру ниже вы можете добавить любые классы и атрибуты для стилизации меню. Это никак не повлияет на функционал.

```js
$('[data-item-role] a')
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('[data-item-role] [data-id="' + id + '"]').addClass('Active');
  })
  .on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('[data-item-role] a').removeClass('Active');
  });
```

```css
.Active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul data-item-role="menu">
  <li><a href="#_" data-id="profileRed">Menu Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" data-id="profileBlue">Menu Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" data-id="profilePink">Menu Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" data-id="profileGreen">Menu Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
<ul data-item-role="menu">
  <li><a href="#_" data-id="profileRed">Menu Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" data-id="profileBlue">Menu Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" data-id="profilePink">Menu Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" data-id="profileGreen">Menu Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
<ul data-item-role="menu">
  <li><a href="#_" data-id="profileRed">Menu Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" data-id="profileBlue">Menu Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" data-id="profilePink">Menu Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#_" data-id="profileGreen">Menu Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Мне нужен первый пример, когда мы помещаем курсор на Menu Item 1, он активируется, Menu Item 1 из 2-го меню и Menu Item 1 из 3-го меню,активируется параллельно.

Comment: Меню разные по дизайну

Comment: @AlexandruSmolenschi Т.е. вы наоборот хотите, чтобы у вас одновременно пункты меню выделялись? Тогда посмотрите исправленный код в вашем вопросе. Он работает так, как вам нужно?

Comment: Да, верно Спасибо большое  "VenZell" Я получил правильный ответ

Comment: Но классы в css разные для разных меню, это еще одна проблема

Comment: @AlexandruSmolenschi "классы в css разные для разных меню" - Нам сквозь интернет плохо видны мысли в Вашем мозгу.